# samba mount not seen on windows 10, how to confirm connection?

Tags: centos7, samba, windows-10

I am attempting to link a lab sequencer to our linux server(centos 7) via samba. The seqeuencer is running windows 10 and it connected to our network. I have configured access on the Server and enabled smb on windows 10. I have rebooted the sequencer as well.

When I try and connect the driver I see nothing.

Is there a way to test the connection to samba from the command line in windows?

samba config from server. I checked and the workgroup is the same..

What else should I do on either platform?

testparm

```
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (8192) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Processing section "[homes]"
Processing section "[printers]"
Processing section "[print$]"
Processing section "[nextseq]"
Processing section "[iseq]"
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

# Global parameters
[global]
    dos charset = CP932
    map to guest = Bad User
    printcap name = cups
    security = USER
    server max protocol = SMB2
    idmap config * : backend = tdb
    cups options = raw


[homes]
    browseable = No
    comment = Home Directories
    inherit acls = Yes
    read only = No
    valid users = %S %D%w%S


[printers]
    browseable = No
    comment = All Printers
    create mask = 0600
    path = /var/tmp
    printable = Yes


[print$]
    comment = Printer Drivers
    create mask = 0664
    directory mask = 0775
    path = /var/lib/samba/drivers
    write list = root


[nextseq]
    path = /storage/nextseq
    read only = No
    valid users = @smbgroup


[iseq]
    path = /storage/iseq
    read only = No
    valid users = @smbgroup
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the sequencer connects only with smb1. If so configure it to use smb2. SMB1 has known security issues and is not enabled by default. Otherwise configure the samba server to accept smb1.